# Adobe Air - Memory problems

Tags: javascript, caching, air, adobe

Everytime I make an Ajax request (jQuery) in Adobe Air and loading an image from an external url, the private memory usage increases. Is there any way to disable the cache of images or purge cached files?

Example:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: someurl,
success: function(res){
    $('#mydiv').attr('src', res);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the garbage collector frees the memory assigned to unused variables, or variables at the end of their scope. Here, `res` is purged at the end of the callback function.

This is what happens in the most common browsers, anyway. I don't really know what happens in Adobe Air, but IIRC it uses WebKit so it *should* behave like Chrome and Safari...

If it doesn't, try to explicitly trigger the garbage collector assigning `null` to unused variables:

```
...
success: function(res){
    $('#mydiv').attr('src', res);
    res = null;
}
```

Anyway, remember that you've still copied the value of `res` in the `src` attribute of the image, so the memory usage will *still* be increased. This should be obvious, anyway.